# Incrementar el valor de una celda MYSQL a través de PHP

Tags: php, mysql, update

En primer lugar, tengo una base de datos en MYSQL en ella almaceno "productos" y "votos".

```
    <?php 
    $sql="SELECT id,producto,voto FROM participar";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['producto'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['voto'] ?></td>
        <form action="sumar.php" method="post">
        <td><input type="submit" name="boton1" value="Votar"></td>
        </form>
```

El resultado es una tabla donde aparece los productos, los votos y un botón para votar en cada fila generada a través del while. La idea es que cuando alguien pulse el botón aumente en +1 el número de votos de ese determinado producto.

Mi problema está en cómo hacer que el botón que sea clicado solo aumente los votos del ID del producto correspondiente.

```
    <?php 
    include "conexion.php";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    $update="UPDATE participar SET voto=voto+1 WHERE id="";
    mysqli_query($mysqli,$update);
     ?>
```

No llego a ver cómo puedo hacer para que el botón de la fila correspondiente reciba el "id" del artículo de su misma fila y este aumente.

Seguramente sea una duda muy básica, estoy iniciándome en este mundo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que agregar el id al formulario y enviarlo:

```
<form action="sumar.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="producto_id" value="<?php echo $mostrar['id'] ?>"
    <input type="submit" name="boton1" value="Votar">
</form>
```

En tu archivo *sumar.php* debes comprobar antes de nada que lo que te llega es lo que esperas. Eso lo dejo de lado en esta respuesta.

Una vez hecho esto, ya puedes trabajar con él:

```
<?php 
    include "conexion.php";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    ....

    $id = limpiarVariable($_POST['producto_id']);
    $update="UPDATE participar SET voto=voto+1 WHERE id=".$id;
    ...
```